# (PC) Word 2016 page numbering

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, page-numbers

Main body of the document has multiple sections, numbered 'page X of Y', and then have enclosures at the end that are numbered separately.  These enclosures throw off the {numpages} total for the main body.

Example - Pages 1 - 10 are main body, labelled page 1 of 10, 2 of 10, etc.  When I add a 4 page enclosure, the main body changes to page 1 of 14 through 10 of 14, then the next page is the enclosure and is labelled 1 of 1 (using {sectionpages})...

Comment: You need to use page breaks and mess with page number options for such items as `start numbering from`. Word page numbering and page formatting is a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks @Kinnectus,
I'm trying to get Word to _stop_ counting pages at a certain point.  I have looked at everything I can find (so far) regarding the use of page & section breaks, and so for nothing I've found points me at anything like 'page X of {these sections only}' . . . Any other ideas?  I know I might be trying to get Word to do something it isn't set up to do, but I'm sure it has to be able to especially with college students writing papers with appendices and such at the end???

Comment: Use sections breaks to start renumbering in a new section.